# How to change a javascript css image based on a function on the <select> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have this select object:

```
<select id="alunos" onchange="arteAluno(this);">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="loadImage();">Aluno 1</option>
    <option value="../Index.html">Aluno 2</option>  
    <option value="../Index.html">Aluno 3</option>
</select>
```

and this function:

```
function arteAluno (sel) {
    var url = sel[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location = url;
}
```

and I was making the page change with this. But now I want to get this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function O(obj) {
        return document.getElementById(obj);
    }
    function loadImage() {
        O('arte').style.backgroundImage="url(aikido.jpg)";
        O('arte').style.width = '200px';
        O('arte').style.height = '160px';
    }
})
```

and make this function loadImage only be triggered when I select one of the options of the  tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, you might just as well use it for everything here. You only need to bind one `.change()` handler which sets `window.location` if one of the URLs is chosen, and executes the `loadImage()` function otherwise.

Rather than call the function name `loadImage()` in the `<option>` value (which looks strange), I have replaced it below with a special value `value='load_image'`.  The `.change()` handler will look for that value and execute the function if found.

```
<select id="alunos">
   <option selected="selected"></option>
   <!-- Special value rather than function name here -->
   <option value="load_image">Aluno 1</option>
   <!-- URL values -->
   <option value="../Index.html">Aluno 2</option>  
   <option value="../Index.html">Aluno 3</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Bind the onchange event for select#alunos
  $('#alunos').change(function() {
    // If the load_image option was selected, call the loadImage() function
    if ($(this).val() == 'load_image') {
      loadImage();
    }
    // Otherwise, load the URL
    else {
     // Unless the blank option is selected...
     if ($(this).val() !== '') {
       window.location = $(this).val();
     }
    }
  });
});
// Can replace with all jQuery (since you are using it anyway)
function loadImage(){
  $('#arte').css('backgroundImage', 'url(aikido.jpg)');
  $('#arte').css('width', '200px');
  $('#arte').css('height', '160px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to intercept the selectedIndex (or the value) and call your function in your own code:

```
function arteAluno (sel) {
    var url = sel[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    if(url=='loadImage();') {
        loadImage();
        return;
    } 
    window.location = url;
}
```